# Converting an integer to a string doesn't work

Tags: php, html, string, integer

I have a little problem... And I have looked up everywhere how to convert an integer to a string. I found several ways of doing it, but with no success. So right now I have no idea of what the problem might be. I thought that I should ask you if also other people have the same problem as I do.

So what doesn't work:

```
$inputname = rand(1, 10000);
    $inputname = "$inputname";
    echo '
        <h3>Translate to English</h3>
        <form name="word" method="post" action="">
            <table border="0">
                <tr><td><label>Swedish:</label></td><td width="200"><input type="text" name="swe" maxlength="100" value="'.$swe.'" readonly /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label>English:</label></td><td width="200"><input type="text" name="'.$inputname.'" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="nextword" value="Next Word" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    ';

    if (isset($_POST['nextword'])) {
        $eng = $_POST[$inputname];
        $swe = $_POST['swe'];
        $word = $row['id'];
        if($eng == $row['eng']){
            mysql_query("UPDATE `words` SET `right`='yes' WHERE `id`='$word'");
        }
        else{
            mysql_query("UPDATE `words` SET `right`='no' WHERE `id`='$word'");
        }
```

I don't get any errors, but when I check my database it says right=no even if I typed in the correct word. If I change $inputname to a string using $inputname = "string"; it works... So why doesn't the convert work?

I have tried (string)$var, $var = "$var", mysql_real_escape_string($var) but with no success...

If you have any ideas of how to solve this please respond.

Comment: What are the results of `var_dump($row)` and `var_dump($_POST)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't seen the contents of your variables, you have a logical problem: When you open your page the first time, a form is created with a random name for the English input. Then you submit the form and generate a new random name, so these will probably never ever match.

For example you send in a variable named `$_POST['1234']` and then you look for `$_POST[$inputname]` where `$inputname` has just been generated randomly.

Giving a random name to your form variable is a bad idea because it is not that straightforward to receive it after the form has been submitted.

Apart from that I don't think your `name` attribute can start with a number, but that's not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

---

As others mention, the issue doesn't seem to be integer conversion so much as a problem with the logic.

Perhaps a "poor man's debugging session" might shed some light on the error: To get a better idea of what your script is doing as-is, change the mysql_query lines to simply echo the query to the browser (ie,  `echo "UPDATE`words`SET`right`='yes' WHERE`id`='$word'";` )

You'll then be able to see the SQL statements being made (which are most likely not what you think they are), and should help you see the error more plainly.